# Convert double array to double List array

Tags: java

I have a double array like this:

```
double[] darr = new double[50];
```

and I have some elements in it. How can I convert it to a `List` double array like:

```
 List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
```

Comment: well, now you just need to do `x.add(darr)`, unless you mean `List<Double>` and want to pass the elements from your `double[]` into this `List<Double>`.

Comment: Do you actually want a `List<double[]>` or a `List<Double>`?

Comment: List<double[]> ..  i think luiggi has the right answ.. Thanks anyways..

Answer (score 1):

```
double[] darr = new double[50];
```

If you want a List of double array then you could user [Arrays.asList(T...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

```
List<double[]> darrList = Arrays.asList(darr);
```

If you want a list of double then you have to create a list, loop over the elements of the array and add each to the list

```
List<Double> dList = new ArrayList<Double>(darr.length);
for(double d : darr) {
    dList.add(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well i have the  right answer just need to do `x.add(darr)`

Comment: Then please accept the answer that was right.  Click on the green tick beside it.

Answer (score -1):

If it is possible to use `Double[]` instead of `double[]` you can convert it to `List<Double>` with one command:

```
Double[] darr = new Double[50];
List<Double> x = Arrays.asList(darr);
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants to accomplish.

Comment: Read the comments on question and OP's answer.

Comment: Nothing about `Double[]` in your message.

Comment: Again: OP just want/needs a `List<double[]>` and provided an answer about it. Period.